# MySQL date format is not supported

Tags: mysql

When we call this procedure

```
Call get_reports_by_time('2014-12-22 11:19:26 AM').
```

no data is returned

but when we call this

```
Call get_reports_by_time('2014-12-22 11:19:26 ')
```

all the records for that day is returned. why its so?

Comment: Add your stored procedure code to your posting.

Comment: get_reports_by_time is a function you (or your company) created, so it is relying on a format since you're probably not using timestamps.So we need to see your procedure to be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string representation of dates/timestamps,... is dependent on your db settings.

In your case one representation can be converted to a date (assuming that you work with a date type in your stored procedure) and one representation cannot be converted to a date.

I higly suggest to use date and time types and not any string representation for your paremeters (if you need a string representation then convert it by YOURSELF using [date/str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html))